# UK Standard Visitor Visa advice

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I need advice, My uncle wants to apply for a standard tourist visa to visit the UK from India. He has fairly low income but has savings. But i plan on giving him the money for his flight ticket and will be covering any costs whilst he's here, i can provide proof with bank statements and payslips if required.

When filling in the form it asks for his income, savings ect. It then asks if anyone will be helping. I have put the entire cost of his trip coming to the UK will be covered by myself(Nephew), In the next question it asks why someone will be paying to cover his costs, how can i justify this?

Comment: Why are you paying for his trip? Just write what you feel is the reason

Comment: Mainly due to his low income. The form seems to mention how much he’ll be spending and how much someone else will be giving. Seems a bit misleading

Comment: If someone else contacted you claiming (perhaps even presenting proof of) a low income would you also pay for their trip? Assuming the answer is no, why do you want to pay for your uncle? That's what you need to write.

Comment: Despite your sponsorship, your uncle still needs to demonstrate that he qualifies for a visa. See ‘Sponsorship Issues’ in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: To expand Henrik's point: do you have a close relationship with your uncle? Explain that in your answer on the form. I have uncles whom I have no relationship with and I would not spend money on them or invite them to visit me.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold.